# How to label a svg polygon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have made svg polygons like this:

```
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="180px" height="113px" viewBox="-9.25 6.98 209 196" enable-background="new -18.25 -18.75 200 180" xml:space="preserve">
      <g>
        {% for i in range (1,5) %}
        <polygon class="sl" index="{{i}}"  fill="{{colors[i].fill}}" points="{{colors[i].points }}" x="0px" y="0px" msg="{{ understand.msg }}"/>
        {% endfor %}
      </g>
    </svg>
```

I want to show a value along with each Polygon. Till now I tried this:

```
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="180px" height="113px" viewBox="-9.25 6.98 209 196" enable-background="new -18.25 -18.75 200 180" xml:space="preserve">
      <g>
        {% for i in range (1,5) %}
        <polygon class="sl" index="{{i}}"  fill="{{colors[i].fill}}" points="{{colors[i].points }}" x="0px" y="0px" msg="{{ understand.msg }}">
          <text>{{value}}</text>
          </polygon>
        {% endfor %}
      </g>
    </svg>
```

this didn't work. Is there any way i can label the polygons?

```
<svg xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new -18.25 -18.75 200 180" viewBox="-9.25 6.98 209 196" height="113px" width="180px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
          <g>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="80.351,140.188 56.09,98.165 104.612,98.165" fill="#F9F8F9" index="1" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="108.143,92.084 83.882,50.061 132.405,50.061 " fill="#C0E7D2" index="2" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="52.752,92.084 28.491,50.061 77.014,50.061 " fill="#FCC3CD" index="4" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="104.65,94.235 56.128,94.235 80.39,52.212 " fill="#F0EDEE" index="3" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="136.041,44.023 111.78,2 160.303,2 " fill="#0E9935" index="5" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">1</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="80.651,44.023 56.39,2 104.914,2 " fill="#E2DEDE" index="7" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="132.549,46.177 84.028,46.177 108.289,4.155" fill="#A5DDBE" index="6" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="25.262,44.024 1,2.001 49.524,2.001 " fill="#FE364E" index="9" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                        <polygon msg="" y="0px" x="0px" points="77.161,46.177 28.636,46.177 52.898,4.153 " fill="#F9A8B6" index="8" class="sl">
              <text fill="red" y="" x="">0</text>
            </polygon>
                      </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: colors[i].points have many points or single points...?

Comment: many..diffrent for difrent value of i

Comment: Whatever template language you may be using to create your SVG is irrelevant, yes? If so, I would suggest showing only final generated code in your question.

Comment: @Phrogz Please see edit. I have added the generated svg content. Presently text has no coordinates since i cant figure out what should go in there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the help provided above worked but some how center of the polygon was becoming the probelm.

I went o a bit of geometry ;) and used this to calculate center of my polygon

```
  $points = explode(' ', $understand['points']);
  foreach ($points as $point) {
    if ($point != '') {
      $poi = explode(',', $point);
      $xcordinates[] = $poi[0];
      $ycordinates[] = $poi[1];
    }
  }
  $understand['x'] = ($xcordinates[0] + $xcordinates[1] + $xcordinates[2])/3;
  $understand['y'] = ($ycordinates[0] + $ycordinates[1] + $ycordinates[2])/3;
```

and in HTML i did this:

```
  <polygon class="sl" index="{{}}"  fill="{{}}" points="{{understanding[key].points }}"  msg="{{ understand.msg }}"/>
        <text  x="{{color[key].x}}" y="{{color[key].y}}" fill="black">{{value}}</text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to position the text explicitly

```
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="180px" height="113px" viewBox="-9.25 6.98 209 196" enable-background="new -18.25 -18.75 200 180" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    {% for i in range (1,5) %}
    <polygon class="sl" index="{{i}}"  fill="{{colors[i].fill}}" points="{{colors[i].points }}" x="0px" y="0px" msg="{{ understand.msg }}"></polygon>
    <text x="{{x_center_of_poly}}" y="{{y_center_of_poly}}" fill="red">{{value}}</text>
    {% endfor %}
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: actually all the points are diffrent. There is no pre defined centr point also

Comment: your going to have to decide on where you want the text to display relative to the points in the polygon and calculate appropriate values and pass them into the template then

Answer (score 0):

Polygon Points have to change , Atleast we have to mention three co-ordinate points value for polygon and mention the `x,y` co-ordinate for the text

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/tBcq4/)**